# Are there good tools or techniques to debug InstanceCountViolation in Android's StrictMode?

Tags: android

I'm seeing something like the following in my Android logs:

```
android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.myemployer.whatever.SomeActivity; instances=3; limit=1
```

I'm assuming that some long-lived object is keeping references to every instance of my activity but I'm finding it really hard to debug. Are there any good tools or techniques to find the root cause of issues like this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [eclipse memory analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) in conjunction [with the ADT](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) for tracking down all sorts of memory problems - very useful for memory leaks, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Found my problem using those two tools. Something in the libraries I use is holding on to Thread objects by sticking them in a map. I was creating Thread objects with anonymous callback objects in them, which hold an implicit reference to my Activity. I would have never found this without those tools.